# Proxying requests in a create-react-app application

Tags: reactjs, proxy, create-react-app

I have been looking all over to try and figure out why this doesn't work. I have two applications, a client and a server. I'd like to proxy the client requests to the server. I have a route called `/api/repositories`. I can't have the proxy in the package.json, because it needs to work in production, also.

It is a Create React App project. Here are the important files.

`setupProxy.js`

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.use(
    createProxyMiddleware("/api", {
      target: "http://my.server.com",
      changeOrigin: true,
      onProxyReq: (proxyReq) => {
        console.log("logged");
        if (proxyReq.getHeader("origin")) {
          proxyReq.setHeader("origin", "http://my.server.com");
        }
      },
    })
  );
};
```

And I use it in a functional React component called Searchbar, as such:

`Searchbar.js`

```
import axios from "axios"

async function getRepos() {
  const response = await axios({
    method: "GET",
    url: "/api/repositories",
  });

  return response.data;
}

function Searchbar() {
  const [repos, setRepos] = useState([]);

  // Get the repos on load
  useEffect(async () => {
    setRepos(await getRepos());
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {repos.map((repo) => <p>{repo}<p>)}
    </div>
  );

}
```

However, when I run `npm run start` and run the development server, all of my API requests are going to `http://localhost:3000/api/repositories`, which obviously returns a 404 error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try this: [Using React's Proxy to get ahead of CORS & use HTTPS for API calls](https://blog.praveen.science/using-reacts-proxy-to-get-ahead-of-cors/) and use an API Gateway on production?

Comment: I cannot add a proxy in my `package.json` file, since that will only affect it in development mode, and I need it to work in production. I deploy this with Heroku, which breaks the build if there is a proxy left in the `package.json`.

Comment: What breaks in Heroku? You shouldn't be using the dev server at all in production.

Comment: When I deploy this project on Heroku, I have the Procfile set as: `web: npm run start`. It builds correctly, but I get an HTML page that just says "Invalid Host Headers" when I visit the page I've deployed to. The internet tells me that this means I have left the proxy property in my `package.json` file, and when I remove it, it deploys and renders correctly.